# How to programmatically know the primary keys of a table in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using `Datastax driver` to access `cassandra`. My method takes a `cql string paramater`.
Because the cql is arbitrary,  I don't know the `primary keys` of the table in the cql string.

In ResultSet, I didn't find the `metadata` associated with the `primary keys`.
I can only get the `names` and `values` of `all columns`.

I'd like to know which columns are primary keys.
How to `programmatically` get the primary keys of the table in the cql?

```
public Map<String, Object> search(String cql) {

    SimpleStatement statement = new SimpleStatement(cql);
    ResultSet result = session.execute(statement);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use `TableMetadata.getPrimaryKey()` method**

Here is a sample demo to get the primary key of keyspace 'test' and table `ashraful_test`

```
try (Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra").build(); Session session = cluster.connect("test")) {
    System.out.println(cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspace(session.getLoggedKeyspace()).getTable("ashraful_test").getPrimaryKey());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any driver stuff but if everything fails you can do following:

```
cqlsh> select column_name, kind from system_schema.columns where keyspace_name ='test' and table_name = 'authorization';

 column_name             | kind
-------------------------+---------------
 authorization_reference |       regular
            order_number | partition_key
              partner_id |    clustering
        sales_channel_id |    clustering
```

Comment: I also know this. But I just want a better solution. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

with com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;

getCqlSession().getMetadata().getKeyspace("my_keyspace").get().getTable("my_table").get().getPrimaryKey()